# Making a rotating and transforming object in VTK

Tags: tcl, transform, scale, vtk

I'm trying to make a rotating cube which alters its scale (in every axis) until 180 degrees and then slowly scales back down.

So far, I've got this:

```
package require vtk
package require vtkinteraction

set xLength 2
set yLength 2
set zLength 2

vtkCubeSource cube
    cube SetXLength $xLength
    cube SetYLength $yLength
    cube SetZLength $zLength
    cube SetCenter 2 2 2

vtkPolyDataMapper cubeMapper
    cubeMapper SetInput [cube GetOutput]

vtkActor cubeActor
    cubeActor SetMapper cubeMapper
    [cubeActor GetProperty] SetColor 1 0.45 0
    [cubeActor GetProperty] SetDiffuse 0.9
    [cubeActor GetProperty] SetSpecular 0.45
    [cubeActor GetProperty] SetSpecularPower 20

vtkRenderer ren
vtkRenderWindow renWin 
    renWin AddRenderer ren

vtkRenderWindowInteractor iren
    iren SetRenderWindow renWin
    iren AddObserver UserEvent {wm deiconify .vtkInteract}
    iren Initialize

wm withdraw .

ren AddActor cubeActor
ren SetBackground 0.7 0.7 0.7
renWin SetSize 900 900

for {set i 0} {$i < 360} {incr i} {

    if {[expr $i % 2] == 0} {
        set xLength 3
        set yLength 3
        set zLength 3
    } else {
        set xLength 1
        set yLength 1
        set zLength 1
    }

    renWin Render
    [ren GetActiveCamera] Azimuth 1

}

vtkCommand DeleteAllObjects
```

I don't really know how to make it properly to make a smooth transition along the scale and render that change every cycle iteration. Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem that you're most likely having is that your code is too fast. By the time you've drawn one frame, you're already pushing through the next. Slow Down! (This would be just as big a problem if you were animating 2D graphics with plain Tk.)

You want to run the event loop for a little bit between each step. Perhaps like this (you might need to tune the `2`, and the `"yes"` is just some arbitrary value that doesn't matter; what matters is that you're setting the `GoOn` variable causing the `vwait` to stop servicing the event loop):

```
after 2 set GoOn "yes"
vwait GoOn
```

Put that straight after these lines:

```
renWin Render
[ren GetActiveCamera] Azimuth 1
```

Now that you've given a little time for the animation to actually be perceived by the user, you ought to have something that is much easier to see as smooth. You don't have to process *that* many frames a second for the brain to figure that the motion is smooth: movies make do with 24, TV with 30 (in the US) or 25 (in Europe)…